# Difference in output - Java

Tags: java

There isn't an error message appearing in my code.
However, I get different outputs when I type my code in the main and when i call my methods.

```
package card;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *

 */
public class Card {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static String rank;
    static String suit;
    static String[] ranks = {"2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    static String[] suits = {"Spades","Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
    static Card[] deck = new Card[52];

   public Card(String rank, String suit)
   {
      this.rank = rank;
      this.suit = suit;
   }

   public static String getRank()
   {
       return rank;
   }

   public static void setRank(String r)
   {
       rank = r;
   }

    public static String getSuit()
   {
       return suit;
   }

   public static void setSuit(String s)
   {
       suit = s;
   }





    public static void init(Card[] deck)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<deck.length; x++)
        {
            Card newCard = new Card(ranks[x%13], suits[x/13]);
            deck[x] = newCard;
        }
    }

    public static void swap(Card[] deck, int a, int b)
    {
        Card temp = deck[a];
        deck[a] = deck[b];
        deck[b] = temp;
    }

    public static void shuffle(Card[] deck)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int x = 0; x<deck.length; x++)
        {
            swap(deck, x, (rnd.nextInt(deck.length)));
        }
    }

    public static void print(Card[] deck)
    {   
        for(int x =0; x<deck.length; x++)
        {
              System.out.println(deck[x].getRank() + " of " + deck[x].getSuit());
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


    for(int x = 0; x<deck.length; x++)
    {
        Card cards = new Card(ranks[x%13], suits[x/13]);
        deck[x] = cards;
        System.out.println(deck[x].getRank() + " of " + deck[x].getSuit());

        //init(deck);
        //print(deck);
    }


  }

}
```

For doing my codes in the main manually without any methods, i will get the correct output:

Eg

```
10 of Diamonds
J of Diamonds
Q of Diamonds
K of Diamonds
```

But when i call the methods, i get the following output:

```
A of Diamonds
A of Diamonds
A of Diamonds
A of Diamonds
A of Diamonds
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "when i invoke the methods"? How are you running them without running the `main` method?

Comment: when i call the method eg: init(), print()

Comment: Have you tried to use a Debugger to find out what is happend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your following static members

```
static String rank;
static String suit;
```

shouldn't be static, since each Card should have different values :

```
String rank;
String suit;
```

Comment: thank you. from my understanding, doesn't static refers to attribute that belongs to the class?

Comment: @Aloysius static means that all instances of the class share a single instance of the static variable. Hence all Card instances have the same `rank` and `suit` in your case.

Comment: Oh, as in the variable value won't change. am i right to say this?

Comment: @Aloysius It will change whenever you assign a new value to it, but each time you change it, that change will be seen by all the Card instances.